# how to animate svg path in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, svg, css-transitions, browser-support

this code works on chrome, but not in safari, firefox. Is there any possible way to do this with jQuery?

```css
svg .cls-1 {
  d: path("M.37,1.32V120.37C207.06,182.09,430.47,238,587.2,247.54c13.49.11,247.13,41.9,432.89-203.6q17.89-21.5,35.11-42.62Z");
  -webkit-animation: 20s top-wave linear infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: 20s top-wave linear infinite alternate;
  animation: 20s top-wave linear infinite alternate
}
@keyframes top-wave {
  from, to {
    d: path("M.37,1.32V120.37C207.06,182.09,430.47,238,587.2,247.54c13.49.11,247.13,41.9,432.89-203.6q17.89-21.5,35.11-42.62Z")
  }
  50% {
    d: path("M.37,1.32V120.37C207.08,082.09,330.47,238,587.2,47.54c13.49.11,247.13,41.9,432.89-203.6q17.89-21.5,35.11-42.62Z")
  }
}
```

```html
//svg element
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" class=" bg-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Shape_1" data-name="Shape 1">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M.37,1.32V120.37C207.06,182.09,430.47,238,587.2,247.54c13.49.11,247.13,41.9,432.89-203.6q17.89-21.5,35.11-42.62Z" transform="translate(-30.37 -0.32)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: do you tried use  @-moz- ?

Comment: yes , bt not working....

Comment: `d` is not an attribute that can be styled with CSS in the current SVG standard (1.1).  It *is* allowed in SVG 2. But, so far, only Chrome has implemented that. You will need to use `<animate>` for now - as per Randy's answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use animate tag

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" class=" bg-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Shape_1" data-name="Shape 1">
    <path class="cls-1" transform="translate(-30.37 -0.32)"d="M.37,1.32V120.37C207.06,182.09,430.47,238,587.2,247.54c13.49.11,247.13,41.9,432.89-203.6q17.89-21.5,35.11-42.62Z" >
      
      <!-- animate tag -->
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M.37,1.32V120.37C207.06,182.09,430.47,238,587.2,247.54c13.49.11,247.13,41.9,432.89-203.6q17.89-21.5,35.11-42.62Z" to="M.37,1.32V120.37C207.08,082.09,330.47,238,587.2,47.54c13.49.11,247.13,41.9,432.89-203.6q17.89-21.5,35.11-42.62Z"
        dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      
       <!-- animate tag  END-->

    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: after first cycle of transitions svg return to intial path suddenly, bt i need  animation while svg return to initial path @RANDY

Comment: The attribute will change from the initial value to the end value and want to return to its inital value with animation

Comment: Check this guide to svg animation ---> https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/